cordova-ios 7.1.0 privacy-manifest correct format?
I have an ionic cordova app. Apple is now requiring us to provide reasons for certain API access in our privacy-manifest.
I need to add "CA92.1" as the reason for NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults.
I see cordova-ios 7.1.0 includes the ability to add a privacy-manifest to the config file.
I updated my cordova-ios to version 7.1.0 and updated my config.xml to look like this:
 <platform name="ios">
        <privacy-manifest>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</key>
                    <string>CA92.1</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </privacy-manifest>
        .....

I also tried without the <dict/> tag
however I got an email from Apple:

ITMS-91056: Invalid privacy manifest - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file from the following path is invalid: “PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy”. While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, keys and values in your app’s privacy manifest must be in a valid format. For more details about privacy manifest files, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files.

Any ideas on how to adjust this to the correct format? Thanks :)
Added information:
This is how cordova-ios describes it should be formatted:
https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2024/04/03/cordova-ios-7.1.0.html

I think I've figured it out. The correct format was:
 <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
 <array>
      <dict>
           <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
           <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
           <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
           <array>
                <string>CA92.1</string>
           </array>
      </dict>
 </array>

I also added all of the other properties. So for an example privacy-manifest.xml for others you can use mine as a template:
<privacy-manifest>
    <key>NSPrivacyTracking</key>
    <false />
    <key>NSPrivacyTrackingDomains</key>
    <array />
    <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeDeviceID</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false />
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeEmailAddress</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false />
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeName</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeProductPersonalization</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false />
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePaymentInfo</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false />
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePhoneNumber</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false />
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePhotosorVideos</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeProductPersonalization</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false />
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeProductInteraction</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAnalytics</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false />
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurchaseHistory</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeProductPersonalization</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false />
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeUserID</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeProductPersonalization</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false />
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeOtherDataTypes</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false />
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePhysicalAddress</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
            <true />
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
            <array>
                <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeOther</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
            <false />
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
            <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
            <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
            <array>
                <string>CA92.1</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</privacy-manifest> 


This is something I found on internet that didn't worked and I was still getting emails from Apple with invalid privacy manifest

This format is working and accepted by apple

I had to create the file from Xcode and add API declarations from there or you can copy correct format after adding PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy from Xcode and I'm no longer receiving any emails from Apple complaining about invalid format or missing API Deceleration
To create new PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy form Xcode here

I stumbled over a good website to generate a privacy manifest manifest-maker which you can copy into your config.xml between <privacy-manifest></privacy-manifest>. Just remember to remove
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>

And their respective closing tags when you copy it into config.xml
